# Hibernate: Association mapping vs Inheritance

Tags: hibernate

I am new in hibernate and came across association mapping and inheritance. They seem to do exactly the same thing, from what I understand.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: An Apple is a Fruit. That's inheritance. A Basket contains Fruits, a Fruit is contained in a Basket. That's an association. It doesn't have much to do with Hibernate. More with OO.

Comment: @David G : Thank buddy to clear it

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Association Mapping and Inheritance in Hibernate is almost same as in any OO programming Language.

```
Association Mapping indicates HAS-A Relationship.
Inheritance indicates acquiring the properties of Parent Class to Child Class.
```

Like You told both seem the same, Yes you are right. Both directly or Indirectly inheriting the properties or behaviour of Other class to a class. In Hibernate or In any ORM, It will be only properties as It deals with only data.

We have Association mappings like **OneToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany**.
In all the association mappings, we use only two tables except in ManyToMany where we use Bridge table.

The POJO class OneToOne annotation or ManyToOne annotation will refer the row in the other table using the foreign key.

So In OneToOne mapping, Any of the tables can be referred to the other table.
(We must specify here where table should refer the other using the mappedBy attribute)

In OneToMany, we dont have any confusion.
In ManyToMany, we have two OneToMany associations with Bridge Table. So applies as the OneToMany for each Individual relation.

Inheritance can be achieved by **Table per Concrete class, Table per Subclass and Table per Hierarchy.**

In Inheritance mappings, when one table is used for multiple classes, Hibernate use discriminator columns to discriminate the data to indicate which rows actually belong to which Entity.

In Table per concrete approach, the table inherits the columns(properties or variables in POJO classes) of Abstract classes.

In Table per Hierarchy approach, It maintains only one table per the entire hierarchy approaches.

In Table per subclass approach, It maintains table for each subclass. For example, If there are two branches (subclasses) from a Single Entity. Then, there will be two tables.

Comment: thanks for the write up! is it possible to use both Inheritance and Associations in Hibernate?